# Using Catchoom in C# WP8.1 project

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows-phone-8, dotnet-httpclient

i want to use [catchoom](http://catchoom.com/documentation/api/recognition/) in c# , but not able to find any sample could any one please provide any sample code if have.

i have got this sample of curl

```
 curl -F "image=@CATask1-Correct.png" -F "token=sometoken" https://r.catchoom.com/v1/search
```

Can some one covert this to c# ? 
I tried to convert it as shown below:

Here's my code:

```
public static async Task<string> Upload(byte[] image)
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
           // string boundary = "---XXX---";
            using (var content =  new MultipartFormDataContent())
            {

                string token = "sometoken";
                MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
                StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream);
                writer.Write(token);
                writer.Flush();
                stream.Position = 0;

               // adding Token and Image to the request 
                content.Add(new StreamContent(stream), "token");

                content.Add(new StreamContent(new MemoryStream(image)), "bilddatei", "upload.jpg");

                using (

                     var message = await client.PostAsync("https://r.catchoom.com/v1/search", content)) 

                       {
                    var input = await message.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                    return input;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

then I called the method in the on-click event handler:

```
     private async void mybtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        // converting the image to a byte array
        BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage(new Uri("http://www.familyfuntwincities.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/apple_red_1_clipart.png?s=128&g=1"));
        RandomAccessStreamReference rasr = RandomAccessStreamReference.CreateFromUri(bitmapImage.UriSource);
        var streamWithContent = await rasr.OpenReadAsync();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[streamWithContent.Size];
        await streamWithContent.ReadAsync(buffer.AsBuffer(), (uint)streamWithContent.Size, InputStreamOptions.None);

 // calling the upload method
        string output = await Upload(buffer);
        mytext1.Text = output;

    }
```

but I keep getting "image is missing" error from the catchoom server although I managed to upload the image to other servers in the same way ( without the token part of course).

My question is: How to add multipule part content? what's the right boundary between the Token part and the image part in order to be recognized by catchoom?

Answer (score 0):

Here is what worked for me:

```
public static async Task<string> Test(string token, Stream stream, string fileName)
{
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    MultipartFormDataContent content = new MultipartFormDataContent();
    content.Add(new StringContent(token), "token");
    content.Add(new StreamContent(stream), "image", fileName);
    var resp = await client.PostAsync("https://r.catchoom.com/v1/search", content);
    return await resp.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
```

If you wanted to use the image you listed in your sample, here is how I would fetch it:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
var stream = await client.GetStreamAsync("http://www.familyfuntwincities.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/apple_red_1_clipart.png?s=128&g=1");
return await Test("<SOME_TOKEN_VALUE>", stream, "apple.png");
```

However the API claims that the image is unsupported due to alpha transparency.  You can find some other samples that show you how to strip alpha transparency if that is important.  The above code worked fine for images that don't have alpha transparency.